# Using postgis functions in hibernate SQL Query

Tags: hibernate, postgis

I need to execute `select ST_AsText(column_name)` from table using hibernate `createSQlQuery()`.

When i executed that query, it shows that the column name is not found in the result set.
But when i execute the same query in my PGAdmin browser, the query works.

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select ST_AsText(END2536) from country   where        object='something'");
((SQLQuery) query).addScalar(column, Hibernate.STRING);
String geomValue = (String) query.uniqueResult();
query.setCacheable(true);
query.setCacheRegion("query.CommonManagement");
```

Error Msg:

```
16:56:27,076 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.StringType] (http--172.20.211.235-8080-1) could not read column value from result set: END2536; The column name END2536 was not found in this ResultSet.
16:56:27,077 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http--172.20.211.235-8080-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
16:56:27,077 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http--172.20.211.235-8080-1) The column name END2536 was not found in this ResultSet.
16:56:27,080 ERROR [stderr] (http--172.20.211.235-8080-1) org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: Could you add source you use, and the error msg?

Comment: Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select ST_AsText(END2536) from country   where        object='something';
((SQLQuery) query).addScalar(column,Hibernate.STRING);
String geomValue = (String) query.uniqueResult();
query.setCacheable(true);
query.setCacheRegion("query.CommonManagement");

Comment: Error Msg
16:56:27,076 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.StringType] (http--172.20.211.235-8080-1) could not read column value from result set: END2536; The column name END2536 was not found in this ResultSet.
16:56:27,077 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http--172.20.211.235-8080-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
16:56:27,077 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http--172.20.211.235-8080-1) The column name END2536 was not found in this ResultSet.
16:56:27,080 ERROR [stderr] (http--172.20.211.235-8080-1) org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Comment: Please add it to the question, like I did, next time :) And properly format. You'll have higher chance to get an answer.

Comment: thanks. :) do u have any answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys.I figured out the problem. It was because the result set had an alias name and I had enabled query caching. So the column name (END2536) was not in the result set. When i commented the query caching part, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear - says

> The column name END2536 was not found in this ResultSet.

So if you say it work in the client, it seems that Hibernate changes the query somehow.

Enable SQL queries logging as described [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t44119.html) and check what Hibernate sends.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add additional quotes since you are using capital letter(s) for the column name.

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select ST_AsText(\"END2536\") from country   where        object='something'");
```